# Can we combine lib jars in EAR with shared lib reference in Websphere?

Tags: java, websphere, ear

I dont seem to find a solution to that, I have the following problem :

I have a bunch of jar dependencies that are put in lib folder under my ear.

Besides, I put other jars in shared lib references.

When I reference the shared lib, I seem to have ClassNotFound from classes in the lib jar under ear, I do not know if we can actually have access to both anyhow?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming WebSphere traditional, shared libraries associated with the application will share a class loader with jars in the EAR/lib directory, unless you select the "use an isolated class loader" setting for the shared libraries - that gives them their own class loader that is not able to "see" classes in EAR/lib.

If your EAR/lib libraries aren't being found at all (from any scope), I'd suggest checking application.xml to ensure that your application is not declared as a Java EE <5 application - if the application.xml specifies J2EE 1.2-1.4, that predates the addition of library-directory to the specification, and the server will not add that directory to the class path.